# How should we tag questions about ethnic cooking?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Simple tag-related question, but one that I suspect will become important over time: How should we tag questions that relate to recipes, techniques, or equipment from or relating to a specific culture or region of the world?

<sub>(This one's kind of already been decided by the community, but I want to get it out there so that people are aware of it and will hopefully retag when necessary.)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

The community seems to have settled on the `cuisine` suffix, and I think we should keep that.  For example:

- `[italian-cuisine]`
- `[american-cuisine]`
- `[asian-cuisine]` (with possible sub-tag `[chinese-cuisine]` or `[thai-cuisine]`)

There seem to be a few stragglers right now, for example I see `[chinese]`.  If everybody accepts the `cuisine` version, we should retag any ethnic-cooking questions missing the suffix.

(Don't forget the hyphen)

Comment: Would you advocate `[modern-european-cuisine]` in that train of thought?

Comment: @Rowland: I'm not sure what the character limit is, that one might be truncated.  Aside from that, it's probably fine, although I'm not sure if there are cooks out there who would consider themselves experts on such a broad-sounding subject.  As always, use your best judgment; I'm more concerned with the format and consistency of the tags than the validity or effectiveness of specific tags (at least for now).

Comment: I was working on the principle that restaurants tend to like describing their cuisine of Modern European (in the UK at least)

Comment: @Rowland: Haven't heard it here in Canada.  Sounds like maybe it's referring to "fusion" restaurants with influences from all over Europe.  If you think it applies, go for it, although I'd personally try to use a more well-known name if possible (Italian, French, Spanish).

Comment: "Fusion" in the UK would typically be a mix of Far-Eastern and European

Comment: *-shrug-* You can use `[alpha-centauri-cuisine]` if you want, as long as we agree on a consistent style.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that simple might be best.  Would the country of origin suffice?

Comment: Well I certainly don't think that it would be appropriate to tag questions about Chinese cooking with `[china]`.  `[chinese]` is definitely an option but goes against current precedent, and it's also just a wee bit ambiguous (Chinese *what?*).  But we'll see what other people think; you should include a few examples in your post and we'll watch the votes.

Comment: This wouldn't work for Scandinavin cuisine, either